# Separate "Battle Character" class from "Character" class?

Tags: c#

So I have a Class called Character which represents all the player, his companions, and all enemies.  This class does a lot of things including performing actions upon other characters, and upon the environment, and so on.

I'm about to start work on a battle system for this RPG, and there will be the player controlled (and enemy controlled) units which will have a location on the screen, and a delay since their last action, and a ton of other properties and methods that apply entirely to the battle.  But, this thing will also be associated in a one-to-one relationship with a Character which exists separate from a battle.  It will need to access that characters stats for it's battle actions as well as some of it's methods.

So the root of my question is, is it better to create a new "Unit" class, which references the character it's associated with, or should I just expand upon the existing Character class with functions and properties that relate **only** to a battle?  If it matters I'm writing this in C#.

Comment: Subclassing is specialisation. If your `BattleCharacter` really is completely a sub-type of `Character`, then subclass. Can you imagine a situation where a battling `Unit` might represent something other than a `Character`? (Maybe you might later want a `CatapultUnit` in the future which isn't a `Character`.)

Comment: Yeah, Character probably should be named something closer to "Entity".  It's a thing with stats, skills, and it belongs to a Party.  So even a non-living object with stats and skills would be a Character, only with different skills.  I think I'm going to go ahead with "Unit" then.  A follow up question would then be:  What would be the best way to instantatiate this more specialized "Unit" class from an existing "Character" Object?  Can I simply do something like:

    `Unit mainUnit = (Unit)existingCharacter?`

If Unit inherits from Character?  That really would be ideal I think.

Comment: If `Unit` inherits from `Character` and `existingCharacter` is a `Character`, then `Unit mainUnit = (Unit)existingCharacter` would fail, because `Unit` is a subclass of `Character` and some `Character`s might not be `Unit`s. Did you mean the other way around (`Character` subclasses `Unit`)?

Comment: Okay, what I had in my head isn't right then.  If I'm going to go this route I'd need to have my battle view utilizing a `Unit` object.  But if all I had was a `Character` object, and `Unit` inherited from `Character` what would be the best way of setting up a `Unit` object which will have access to the data in an existing `Character` object?

Comment: How about an interface? You could have `Character`s (and anything else even totally unrelated that can participate in a battle) implement `IBattler`; then they'll all be fine to store in an `IBattler`-type variable.

Comment: Does an Interface make sense when only `Character` will be IBattler, and not every instance of `Character` will utilize all IBattler properties.

It is a good way of separating out the code though I think, better than having it all within Character.

Answer (score 2):

There are two principles behind my suggestion, SoC and SRP. That is, Separation of Concerns and the Single Responsibility Principle.

The main thing to note in your case is that your character, so far, is totally unrelated to combat. Generally speaking, if something isn't going to be used somewhere, it shouldn't even *exist* there. Creating things like your combat Unit as wrappers has another related benefit: it is a perfect example of Composition, which is (in the universe of OOP) generally considered a **Good Thing**.

So, happily split things where you can, and where things aren't needed, don't put them. The result will be a non-coupled design which will be easy to extend and maintain. This is a core principle of OOP, no matter the application.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

First, a comment: it doesn't sound like you're using an entity/component model. I highly suggest that, because it will help you with your design, and it will also address this problem.

The "core" problem is not "the current representation of the player (on the map) now needs to go into battle." The problem is sprites, etc. are all specific to your current "view" (let's say the map view, as opposed to the battle view).

What I suggest is this: distil your Player class down to the core, permanent attributes that are there regardless of which view you're looking at. This will likely include:

- Player name
- Current/total health
- Inventory
- Skills
- etc.

Once you have this done, it's just a matter of passing this data from view to view. When you pass it to the world map, it'll create the right sprite and render the player location, and allow you to move him.

When you pass it to the battle view, it'll recreate the right sprites, display health, turns, etc.

So the answer is not "new class" or "subclass," the answer is "extract your data from your current view and pass *that* around instead."

Comment: I actually do have it extracted, and the Map view actually just deals with whatever is given to it by the Character class.  The problem is the Character class would need a large array of methods and properties as it relates to battling, in order for the Battle view to know what to draw or what options to give.  But those methods and properties aren't meaningful outside of a battle.

Comment: @Mason11987 so you should have a `BattlePlayer` class and a `MapPlayer` class. Keep the concerns separate (single responsibility per class), and pass around the shared data.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of **inheritance** is to **exploit** the use of **polymorphism**. You may **put** the **sub-classes in a collection** data structure **which type is the super-class** of those sub-classes and then **iterate** over them, **calling the same method with different implementations**.

For example, when you create the class `Vehicle`. Suppose that when your game character calls forth a meteor down from the sky and then every vehicle in the surrounding AoE explodes. Based on this logic, you may create the method `explode()` in the `Vehicle` class. But, it would make no sense if a `Bicycle` explodes from a meteor crash, it has no fuel, why would it explode?.

The solution is to create the `Explosive` interface with the method `explode()` in it. Cars, buses, trains etc. implements the interface whilst Bicycle does not. So, the `Collection` type should be `Explosive`, iterate over it and call the explode method.

For your case, are you going to put the characters in the same group and call the same method in the future? If not, just create a new super-class.